# Async validation with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, validation

There are a couple of things going wrong. First, how do I catch the error in the template, because the `has-error` class doesn't get applied, even though the response is 404 and the proper code is executed.

Second, this only works the first time around. If I leave the field and then enter it again, each time I press a key I get a `TypeError: validator is not a function` exception (as you can see in the code, I execute this only on `blur`). Where am I going wrong?

**The service call**

```
this.CheckIfUnique = function(code) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("/Api/Codes/Unique/" + code).then(function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function() {
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

**The directive**

```
var uniqueCode = [ "CodeService", function(codeService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.bind("blur", function(e) {
                if (!ctrl || !element.val()) return;
                var currentValue = element.val();
                ctrl.$asyncValidators.uniqueCode = codeService.CheckIfUnique (currentValue);
            });
        }
    };
}];
codeModule.directive("uniqueCode",uniqueCode);
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : ( codeForm.submitted && codeForm.code.$invalid ) || ( codeForm.code.$touched && codeForm.code.$invalid ) }">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="code">Code</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="code" name="code" ng-model="newCode.code" ng-required="true" type="text" unique-code />
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="( codeForm.submitted && codeForm.code.$error.required ) || ( codeForm.code.$touched && codeForm.code.$error.required)">Please enter a code</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="codeForm.code.$pending.code">Checking if the code is available</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="( codeForm.submitted && codeForm.code.$error.uniqueCode ) || ( codeForm.code.$touched && codeForm.code.$error.uniqueCode)">This code already exist</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The MVC controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Unique(string code)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return _db.Codes.Any(x => x.Code = code)
        ? new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        : new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the API gets called only when I leave the field, the exception gets thrown on key down (and only after the first time I leave the field)

**EDIT 2:**

In case someone misses the comment, dfsq's answer works and if you add `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` to the input it'll validate on `blur` only.

Comment: Should the call to `resolve()` be in the success callback instead of the failure in your service call?

Comment: It shoud, my bad :) stuck on this for a whie now, and must have switched 'em at some point. But that still doesn't solve the issue. I edited the Q

Comment: It should be `codeForm.$submitted` too in your markup ;-)

Comment: Just read that that's been implemented, so I'm adding it to the list of changes I need to make

Comment: Beyond that, assuming you're getting the correct data from the server I'm not sure what to suggest. If you stick a break point on your service call or on `link` you should be able to see a snapshot of the DOM at the point validation occurs (in Chrome at least) including the dynamic form classes, which might help diagnose it.

Comment: see dfsq's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide proper validator function. It should use anonymous function that returns promise object (from your service). You also don't need blur event:

```
var uniqueCode = ["CodeService", function(codeService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {            
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.uniqueCode = function(value) {
                return codeService.CheckIfUnique(value);
            };
        }
    };
}];
codeModule.directive("uniqueCode", uniqueCode);
```

In addition, you should clean up service method to not use redundant deferred object:

```
this.CheckIfUnique = function(code) {
    return $http.get("/Api/Codes/Unique/" + code);
};
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks, but I still need the `blur` event because, after I start typing the new code, I make an api call on every key pressed

Comment: And, because it was a two part question, what about the validation message? It still doesn't show it

Comment: fixed the `blur` issue with this `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`

Answer (score 0):

About the other part of your question, the message is not showing because:
For the "Checking the code" message you have `codeForm.code.$pending.code` and it should be `codeForm.code.$pending.uniqueCode`

Here is the plunker working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FH8GBhOipgvvUzrFYlwx?p=preview

Comment: Noticed that literary  10mins ago and I was about to post it here